# swift mailer error 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' on an email that actually works?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

My swift mailer plugin has just thrown up an error because an email address it tried to send to isn't compliant. Problem is - the email is valid.

Basically, I don't want swift mailer to be checking whether or not the email is valid I'd like it send regardless. Is that possible?

here is the code which has the function which displays the error but I don't know if what I would need to change is in here or not (kinda a hack programmer :| )

```
//@require 'Swift/Mime/Headers/AbstractHeader.php';
//@require 'Swift/Mime/HeaderEncoder.php';

/**
 * A Mailbox Address MIME Header for something like From or Sender.
 * @package Swift
 * @subpackage Mime
 * @author Chris Corbyn
 */
class Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader extends Swift_Mime_Headers_AbstractHeader
{

  /**
   * The mailboxes used in this Header.
   * @var string[]
   * @access private
   */
  private $_mailboxes = array();

  /**
   * Creates a new MailboxHeader with $name.
   * @param string $name of Header
   * @param Swift_Mime_HeaderEncoder $encoder
   */
  public function __construct($name, Swift_Mime_HeaderEncoder $encoder)
  {
    $this->setFieldName($name);
    $this->setEncoder($encoder);
    $this->initializeGrammar();
  }

  /**
   * Get the type of Header that this instance represents.
   * @return int
   * @see TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_PARAMETERIZED, TYPE_MAILBOX
   * @see TYPE_DATE, TYPE_ID, TYPE_PATH
   */
  public function getFieldType()
  {
    return self::TYPE_MAILBOX;
  }

  /**
   * Set the model for the field body.
   * This method takes a string, or an array of addresses.
   * @param mixed $model
   * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
   */
  public function setFieldBodyModel($model)
  {
    $this->setNameAddresses($model);
  }

  /**
   * Get the model for the field body.
   * This method returns an associative array like {@link getNameAddresses()}
   * @return array
   * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
   */
  public function getFieldBodyModel()
  {
    return $this->getNameAddresses();
  }

  /**
   * Set a list of mailboxes to be shown in this Header.
   * The mailboxes can be a simple array of addresses, or an array of
   * key=>value pairs where (email => personalName).
   * Example:
   * <code>
   * <?php
   * //Sets two mailboxes in the Header, one with a personal name
   * $header->setNameAddresses(array(
   *  'chris@swiftmailer.org' => 'Chris Corbyn',
   *  'mark@swiftmailer.org' //No associated personal name
   *  ));
   * ?>
   * </code>
   * @param string|string[] $mailboxes
   * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
   * @see __construct()
   * @see setAddresses()
   * @see setValue()
   */
  public function setNameAddresses($mailboxes)
  {
    $this->_mailboxes = $this->normalizeMailboxes((array) $mailboxes);
    $this->setCachedValue(null); //Clear any cached value
  }

  /**
   * Get the full mailbox list of this Header as an array of valid RFC 2822 strings.
   * Example:
   * <code>
   * <?php
   * $header = new Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader('From',
   *  array('chris@swiftmailer.org' => 'Chris Corbyn',
   *  'mark@swiftmailer.org' => 'Mark Corbyn')
   *  );
   * print_r($header->getNameAddressStrings());
   * // array (
   * // 0 => Chris Corbyn <chris@swiftmailer.org>,
   * // 1 => Mark Corbyn <mark@swiftmailer.org>
   * // )
   * ?>
   * </code>
   * @return string[]
   * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
   * @see getNameAddresses()
   * @see toString()
   */
  public function getNameAddressStrings()
  {
    return $this->_createNameAddressStrings($this->getNameAddresses());
  }

  /**
   * Get all mailboxes in this Header as key=>value pairs.
   * The key is the address and the value is the name (or null if none set).
   * Example:
   * <code>
   * <?php
   * $header = new Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader('From',
   *  array('chris@swiftmailer.org' => 'Chris Corbyn',
   *  'mark@swiftmailer.org' => 'Mark Corbyn')
   *  );
   * print_r($header->getNameAddresses());
   * // array (
   * // chris@swiftmailer.org => Chris Corbyn,
   * // mark@swiftmailer.org => Mark Corbyn
   * // )
   * ?>
   * </code>
   * @return string[]
   * @see getAddresses()
   * @see getNameAddressStrings()
   */
  public function getNameAddresses()
  {
    return $this->_mailboxes;
  }

  /**
   * Makes this Header represent a list of plain email addresses with no names.
   * Example:
   * <code>
   * <?php
   * //Sets three email addresses as the Header data
   * $header->setAddresses(
   *  array('one@domain.tld', 'two@domain.tld', 'three@domain.tld')
   *  );
   * ?>
   * </code>
   * @param string[] $addresses
   * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
   * @see setNameAddresses()
   * @see setValue()
   */
  public function setAddresses($addresses)
  {
    return $this->setNameAddresses(array_values((array) $addresses));
  }

  /**
   * Get all email addresses in this Header.
   * @return string[]
   * @see getNameAddresses()
   */
  public function getAddresses()
  {
    return array_keys($this->_mailboxes);
  }

  /**
   * Remove one or more addresses from this Header.
   * @param string|string[] $addresses
   */
  public function removeAddresses($addresses)
  {
    $this->setCachedValue(null);
    foreach ((array) $addresses as $address)
    {
      unset($this->_mailboxes[$address]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Get the string value of the body in this Header.
   * This is not necessarily RFC 2822 compliant since folding white space will
   * not be added at this stage (see {@link toString()} for that).
   * @return string
   * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
   * @see toString()
   */
  public function getFieldBody()
  {
    //Compute the string value of the header only if needed
    if (is_null($this->getCachedValue()))
    {
      $this->setCachedValue($this->createMailboxListString($this->_mailboxes));
    }
    return $this->getCachedValue();
  }

  // -- Points of extension

  /**
   * Normalizes a user-input list of mailboxes into consistent key=>value pairs.
   * @param string[] $mailboxes
   * @return string[]
   * @access protected
   */
  protected function normalizeMailboxes(array $mailboxes)
  {
    $actualMailboxes = array();

    foreach ($mailboxes as $key => $value)
    {
      if (is_string($key)) //key is email addr
      {
        $address = $key;
        $name = $value;
      }
      else
      {
        $address = $value;
        $name = null;
      }
      $this->_assertValidAddress($address);
      $actualMailboxes[$address] = $name;
    }

    return $actualMailboxes;
  }

  /**
   * Produces a compliant, formatted display-name based on the string given.
   * @param string $displayName as displayed
   * @param boolean $shorten the first line to make remove for header name
   * @return string
   * @access protected
   */
  protected function createDisplayNameString($displayName, $shorten = false)
  {
    return $this->createPhrase($this, $displayName,
      $this->getCharset(), $this->getEncoder(), $shorten
      );
  }

  /**
   * Creates a string form of all the mailboxes in the passed array.
   * @param string[] $mailboxes
   * @return string
   * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
   * @access protected
   */
  protected function createMailboxListString(array $mailboxes)
  {
    return implode(', ', $this->_createNameAddressStrings($mailboxes));
  }

  // -- Private methods

  /**
   * Return an array of strings conforming the the name-addr spec of RFC 2822.
   * @param string[] $mailboxes
   * @return string[]
   * @access private
   */
  private function _createNameAddressStrings(array $mailboxes)
  {
    $strings = array();

    foreach ($mailboxes as $email => $name)
    {
      $mailboxStr = $email;
      if (!is_null($name))
      {
        $nameStr = $this->createDisplayNameString($name, empty($strings));
        $mailboxStr = $nameStr . ' <' . $mailboxStr . '>';
      }
      $strings[] = $mailboxStr;
    }

    return $strings;
  }

  /**
   * Throws an Exception if the address passed does not comply with RFC 2822.
   * @param string $address
   * @throws Exception If invalid.
   * @access protected
   */
  private function _assertValidAddress($address)
  {
    if (!preg_match('/^' . $this->getGrammar('addr-spec') . '$/D',
      $address))
    {
      throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException(
        'Address in mailbox given [' . $address .
        '] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'
        );
    }
  }

}
```

Any suggestions?

note: swiftmailer is working for most email addresses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ignoring the overall picture of your question, to turn off the RFC error in this code change _assertValidAddress() like this:

```
private function _assertValidAddress($address)
{
  if (!preg_match('/^' . $this->getGrammar('addr-spec') . '$/D',
    $address))
  {
    //throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException(
    //  'Address in mailbox given [' . $address .
    //  '] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'
    //  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, just to let you know, in the *latest* version, do the same but you need to declare **getDefinition**. This is the latest version of the code:

```
  private function _assertValidAddress($address){
    if (!preg_match('/^' . $this->getGrammar()->getDefinition('addr-spec') . '$/D',
    $address))
  {
    //throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException(
    //  'Address in mailbox given [' . $address .
    //  '] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'
    //  );
  }
}
```

You also cannot remove the final if call to send the email. See the bottom of my code, the if call actually sends the email, remove the comments or comment them out if you wish to include this within another PHP file.

```
<?php
// Explosiveentertainment.co.uk //halal.cc 
include_once "lib/swift_required.php";

/*
 * Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
 * $text is your plain-text email
 * $html is your html version of the email
 * If the reciever is able to view html emails then only the html
 * email will be displayed
 */
$text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\n";
$html = <<<EOM
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
EOM;


// This is your From email address
$from = array('yourcompany@yourcompany.com' => 'Name To Appear');
// Email recipients
$to = array(
  'destination1@example.com'=>'Destination 1 Name',
  'destination2@example.com'=>'Destination 2 Name'
);
// Email subject
$subject = 'Example PHP Email';

// Login credentials
$username = 'yoursendgridusername';
$password = 'yourpassword';

// Setup Swift mailer parameters
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.sendgrid.net', 587);
$transport->setUsername($username);
$transport->setPassword($password);
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message (subject)
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);

// attach the body of the email
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$message->setTo($to);
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

// send message
if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
{
  // This will let us know how many users received this message
  echo 'Message sent out to '.$recipients.' users';
}
// something went wrong =(
else
{
  echo "Something went wrong - ";
  print_r($failures);
}
```