# Swift Mailer: Multi recipients option doesn't work

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

Although there are many same questions, none of the solutions worked for me. Mail gets sent only if there is **only one** recipient otherwise generates error below. Also I'm only sending internal emails, no external.

Any idea?

**CODE:**

```
$to = 'one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com';

$transport  = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('192.168.whatever', 25);
$mailer     = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message    = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test')
                ->setFrom(array('myself@example.com'))
                ->setTo(array($to))
                ->setBody('html content goes here', 'text/html');

$result = $mailer->send($message);

echo $result;
```

**ERROR**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given [one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.' in C:\wamp\www\ssl\swift_emailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php:308 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\ssl\swift_emailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(238): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->_assertValidAddress('lukas.borecki@l...') #1 C:\wamp\www\ssl\swift_emailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(96): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->normalizeMailboxes(Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\ssl\swift_emailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(60): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->setNameAddresses(Array) #3 C:\wamp\www\ssl\swift_emailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleHeaderFactory.php(60): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->setFieldBodyModel(Array) #4 C:\wamp\www\ssl\swift_emailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleHeaderSet.php(75): Swift_Mime_SimpleHead in C:\wamp\www\ssl\swift_emailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php on line 308
```

**LOOKED AT:**

[Swift website](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html)
[swift mailer error 'Swift_RfcComplianceException'....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490042/swift-mailer-error-swift-rfccomplianceexception-on-an-email-that-actually-work)
[Google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/swiftmailer/xuhi7RCe95c)
And many more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
$to = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');
....
->setTo($to)
```

Comment: This is example from swift site: `$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')` Test it. Is it work?

Comment: Try `$to = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com, 'three@example.com');`

Comment: What if multiple recipients with same Email ID and different names. I know that this is the exceptional case but do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

TRy this example with swiftmailer:

### parameters.yml

destinatarios: [email1, email2, email3]

### services:

your service name:
        class: your namespace
        arguments: ["%destinatarios%"]

### the class of the service:

protected $destinatarios;

```
public function __construct($destinatarios)
{
    $this->destinatarios = $destinatarios;
}

->setCc($this->destinatarios)
```